# Higher-order, multi-sorted, non purely equational version of universal algebra ?

Tags: universal-algebra, ct.category-theory, lo.logic

I have been looking around, unsuccessfully, for generalizations of universal algebra based on higher-order logic (rather than first order) and where the relations are not purely equational.  Motivation:  I need a "theory of syntax" for presentations of higher-order, non-equational theories.  Furthermore, I want to be able to specify 'combinators' over these presentations, rigorously.

I am aware of [Lawvere theories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawvere_theory), but these are still equational (and neither particularly higher-order, though the multi-sorted generalization seems straightforward enough).  There is a beginning of model theory done in a logical independent way, i.e. [model theory over an institution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institutional_model_theory); but that seems to concentrate on the model-theoretic aspects, rather than the universal algebra aspects. Perhaps what I am looking for are [sketches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sketch_%28mathematics%29)?

[Edit:] From the various answer below, it seems I should be asking the question "how can I view type theory as a theory of syntax"?  Somehow, that seems like an 'implementation' (as it requires a fair bit of 'encoding'); for example, to express the 'theory of categories' [i.e. (Obj, Mor, id, src, trg, $\circ$) and 5-6 axioms, I need a dependent record.  Plus what is a sort (and sort constructor for Mor), what is an operation, and what is in Prop?  Universal algebra cleanly separates these.

A good question was asked: what theorems do I want?  Well, whatever operations I make on theories, well-formedness of the results will require discharging some obligations -- these obligations should all be finitely expressible (and automatically well-formed).  Furthermore, the resulting syntactic objects and their morphisms should form a finitely co-complete category.  Note that I expect that deciding if a given (presentation of a ) theory has a model to be undecidable.

Comment: Is "universal algebra based on higher order logic" any different from type theory? In addition to what you mentioned, you might want to check out classifying topoi (see *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* by MacLane and Moerdijk). Otherwise, you might find what you need in *Introduction to Higher Order Categorical Logic* by Lambek and Scott.

Comment: I have many suggestions which address one or more parts of your question, but I don't see a generalization which does not seem more model-theoretic than universal-algebraic.  Could you tell us what theorems such a beast might have?  Perhaps a Birkhoff theorem analogue or at least a high-order homomorphism theorem?  Also, if combinators are a large part of the goal, perhaps you should look at some form of combinatory or algebraic logic? Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.03.10

Comment: [Some people][1] say that all type theories can be expressed as quasi-equational theories (also called "essentially equational"). Perhaps these are enough for you?


  [1]: http://wms2.andrew.cmu.edu:81/nmvideo/SCS_lecture2b-4-10-hint.mov

Comment: Thank you all - I have edited my question with respect to these comments.  And I am watching that video now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lawvere theories generalize to higher-order logic in a straightforward way. A first-order hyperdoctrine is a functor $\mathcal{P} : C^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathrm{Poset}$ where $C$ has products and is used to interpret terms in context, plus a small herd of conditions to make substitution and quantifiers work out right.

If you want a hyperdoctrine that can interpret higher-order predicate logic, what you additionally want is to (a) require $C$ to be cartesian closed, and (b) $C$ should have an internal heyting algebra $H$ with the property that for each $X$ in $C$, $\mathit{Obj}(\mathcal{P}(X)) \simeq C(X, H)$. Basically, $H$ models the sort of propositions, and the cartesian closure lets you freely interpret lambda-terms denoting predicates and relations. The bijection $\mathit{Obj}(\mathcal{P}(X)) \simeq C(X, H)$ tells you that the morphisms into $H$ actually do correspond to truth values in context $X$, so you can interpret a higher-order term by interpreting a proposition in $\mathrm{Poset}$ via the functor $\mathcal{P}$, and then transporting it back into $C$.

(I would have made this a comment, but it was too long.)

Comment: This feels like an answer to me - as do some of the comments above.  At least they are pointing me in a number of (hopefully fruitful) directions to look in.

Comment: Of course, this notion of "higher-order hyperdoctrine" is almost the same as "elementary topos"; that is, a topos is just one of these higher-order hyperdoctrines in which furthermore \mathcal{P}(X) must be the poset of subobjects of X (thus, it has "comprehension"). Moreover, any higher-order hyperdoctrine can be augmented to one with this comprehension property by simply adding objects for each existing predicate and morphisms for provably functional relations, without changing the action of P on those objects and morphisms which already exist. (Uh-oh, comment limit. Well, that's enough.)